# How I can solve this problem with the stored procedure in C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have in class view a DataGidView which returns a table `Usuarios`. And I only need the columns `name` and `surname`. I can order the data in the stored procedure with 2 radio buttons. But only I can order by names.

My question is: how can I combine these two columns in the stored procedure?

With the command UNION which is showing an error

```cs
//ClasesBase
public static DataTable OrdenarUsuarioSP()
{
    //Conexion
    SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ClasesBase.Properties.Settings.Default.conex);

    //Comando de consulta
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "spOrdenarUsuario";

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Connection = cnn;

    //Usuario oUsuario = new Usuario();
    //Parametros del comando
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@u", oUsuario.Usu_nombreUsuario);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p", oUsuario.USU_Contraseña1);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ayn", oUsuario.Usu_contraseña);
    //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rol", oUsuario.USU_Rol1);

    ////Abrir la conexion
    //cnn.Open();

    ////Ejecuta la consulta (insert)
    //cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    ////Cierro la conexion
    //cnn.Close();

    // Creo la tabla vacía
    DataTable tabla = new DataTable();

    // Creo el adaptador en base al comando cmd
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    // Lleno la tabla con los datos de la base de datos
    da.Fill(tabla);

    // devuelvo la tabla con los datos
    return tabla;

}  //Views

private void btnOrdenarUsuario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (rbnNombreUsuario.Checked)
    {
        dgvListaUsuarios.DataSource = TrabajarUsuario.OrdenarUsuarioSP();
    }if (rbnApellidoNombre.Checked)
    {
        dgvListaUsuarios.DataSource = TrabajarUsuario.OrdenarUsuarioSP();
    }           
}
```

Stored procedure (I get the error here I think):

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE spOrdenarUsuario
/*
(
@parameter1 int = 5,
@parameter2 datatype OUTPUT
)
*/
AS
    /* SET NOCOUNT ON */
    SELECT * 
    FROM Usuario 
    ORDER BY USU_NombreUsuario ASC

    // I want to combine this to SQL instances
    SELECT * 
    FROM Usuario 
    ORDER BY USU_ApellidoNombre ASC 

    RETURN
```

Comment: How about `SELECT * FROM Usuario ORDER BY USU_NombreUsuario, USU_ApellidoNombre;`...?

Comment: this solve my problem only missing the asc to the end

Comment: the `asc` is the default order. Only specify it if you have a mixed order. Like 1 column is in Ascending(`asc`) and the other is in Descending(`desc`).

Comment: And since you're learning bad coding habits - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @SMor instead which should I use?